# Can't theme react-toolbox navDrawer component

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm trying to change the background color of the `NavDrawer` component, but I've spent about 2 hours now trying every possible combination of classes to no avail. I need to style the inner `.drawerContent` div, not the `.navDrawer` div

First I simply had:

```
//theme.scss
.drawerContent {
  background-color: blue
}

// TestTheme.js
import React from 'react';
import { Layout, NavDrawer, Panel } from 'react-toolbox';
import theme from './theme.scss';

const TestTheme = () => (
  <Layout>
    <NavDrawer
      theme={theme}
    >
      Some Content Here
    </NavDrawer>
    <Panel></Panel>
  </Layout>
);

export default TestTheme;
```

Then, following the lead of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026782/react-toolbox-how-to-apply-theme?rq=1) and [issue #688](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/688), I tried:

```
//theme.scss
.root.navDrawer {
  .drawerContent {
    background-color: blue
  }
}

// TestTheme.js
import React from 'react';
import { Layout, NavDrawer, Panel } from 'react-toolbox';
import theme from './theme.scss';

const TestTheme = () => (
  <Layout>
    <NavDrawer
      className={theme.root}
      theme={theme}
    >
      Some Content Here
    </NavDrawer>
    <Panel></Panel>
  </Layout>
);

export default TestTheme;
```

In both cases, nothing happens to the drawer content, though I can see that in the second case, the `.navDrawer` is indeed getting the `.root` class applied.

For clarity, this does **not** seem to be an issue where the css properties are being applied, but don't take precedence. I am looking at the classes in dev tools and the only class being given to the `.drawerContent` div is the default theme. It looks like the class name of my theme isn't even being appended.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem and a contributor redirect me to this [issue](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/914) (all credits to them)

You have to change your theme to

```
.layout {
  .navDrawer {
    .drawerContent {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

and apply it to the `Layout` component

```
<Layout theme={theme}>
    <NavDrawer>
      Some Content Here
    </NavDrawer>
    <Panel></Panel>
  </Layout>
```